# JS how to know when auth jwt token is expired?

Tags: javascript, jwt

How can I simulate that the auth token in local storage is expired?

This is the jwt:

```
export function parseJwt(token) {
  const base64Url = token.split('.')[0];
  return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Url));
}

export function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const t = parseJwt(token);
  if (t.exp && Date.now() < t.exp * 1000) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And this is localstorage:

```
export const isItemExpired = value => {
  if (value.expiration && Date.now() < value.expiration) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

export const getItemExpiration = () => {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate());
  return d.getTime();
};

export const setItem = (key, data, expiration) => {
  const localStorageState = data;
  if (localStorageState) {
    localStorageState.expiration = expiration || getItemExpiration();
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localStorageState));
};

export const removeItem = key => {
  window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
};

export const getItem = key => {
  let value = null;
  try {
    value = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }

  return value;
};
```

My app throws an error when the session refresh token is expired. I am new to tokens and auth in react. How can I set the expiration to be in 5 seconds after being created so that I can find out what the issue is?

Comment: i don't really understand ur question, im seeing code `if (t.exp && Date.now() < t.exp * 1000)`

Comment: doesn't that work?

Comment: @TheBombSquad what does that line indicate? To expire the token after 1000 seconds? I need to debug my app because when the token expires, my app redirects me to unwanted pages. So if I set the token to expire in seconds I can see where the error is

Comment: and here i thought u knew that it was multiplied by 1000 cuz date(and other time values) r measured in milliseconds

Comment: did u copy paste someone's code????

Comment: I am debugging someones code. I need to know how it works I cant find online resources debugging jwt tokens

Comment: turn `Date().now()` into `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: because by the looks of it, `t.exp` is a timestamp

Comment: also to have `.` attributes to a variable, it needs to be an object.. note `const t = parseJwt(token);` before the expiration check

Comment: *I cant find online resources debugging jwt tokens* -> https://jwt.io is a place where you can inspect your token. exp is a timestamp in the form of a unix epoch time, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.